# Behaviour when reducing instances of a Bluemix application

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an orchestrator service which keeps track of the instances that are running and what request they are currently dealing with. If a new instance is required, I make a REST call to increase the instances and wait for the new instance to connect to the orchestrator. It's one request per instance.

The orchestrator tracks whether an instance is doing anything and knows which instances can be stopped, however there is nothing in the API that allows me to reduce the number of instances stopping a particular instance, which is what I am trying to achieve.

Is there anything I can do to manipulate the platform into deterministically stopping the instances that I want to stop? Perhaps by having long running HTTP requests to the instances I require and killing the request when it's no longer required, then making the API call to reduce the number of instances?

Part of the issue here is that I don't know the specifics of the current behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about CloudFoundry/Instant Runtime applications, all of the instances of an applications are running behind a load balancer which uses round-robin to distribute requests across the instances (unless you have session affinity cookie set up). Differentiating between each instances for incoming requests or manual scaling is not recommended and it's an anti-pattern. You can not control which instance the scale down task will choose.

If you really want that level of control with each instance, maybe you should deploy them as separate applications. MyApp1, MyApp2, MyApp3, etc. All of your applications can have the same route (myapp.mybluemix.net). Each of the applications can now distinguish themselves by their name (VCAP_APPLICATION) allowing you terminate them.

Comment: No requests are made to an instance; when it starts it makes a request to the orchistrator for "work". Once complete, if there is no more work, I'd like to reduce the number of instances running. The issue is, I could have other instances processing "work" and I don't want them to be shutdown when I reduce the number of instances by one. Having a separate apps would work here, but when I want to increase the number of apps - it would become a pain again as I'd have to stage a whole new application.

Comment: I guess I need to know the algorithm by which CF/Bluemix chooses which instance to stop...in order to manipulate it to my needs.

Comment: Have you investigated a serverless platform like OpenWhisk for your application? It might be a better fit than Cloud Foundry. 
App services are only executed when a request comes in, you don't have instances waiting around to perform work. The platform can execute multiple services in parallel to handle scaling. You can bind your services to listen to external event streams and be invoked on-demand when new events occur.

Comment: @JamesThomas - I am trying to fit this square peg into a round hole because I've been asked to. Sadly the politics dictate I must use this platform because the company have shelled out for it, so I am trying to find a way to make it work.

Comment: @Cheetah There's a few ways to make this work but it'll be easier to discuss this outside the SO comments section. If you'd like some help with this, you can email me directly at james.thomasATuk.ibm.com